# PyCharm - project structure - sources vs resources

Tags: pycharm, project-structure

In PyCharm directories could be marked as:

- **Sources**
- **Resources**
- Templates
- Excluded

I wonder what is the difference for sources and resources.

I can't find any informations about my question in documentation. Is there any definition?

Comment: Sources are "source" (```.py```) files. Resources are assets like ```.css```, ```.png```, ```.txt``` and other files.

Comment: @user996142 your comment seems good, it should be the answer. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sources are "source" (`.py`) files. Resources are assets like `.css`, `.png`, `.txt` and other files